# The background attribute in CSS is not working

Tags: html, css, background

The aim is to get the three images appear at these places in the page with these divs: .myArrow,#background-image-position and the span .arrow. However no images appear at all, I have tried all I an I couldn't make them appear.

For some reasons the images do not appear at all. Can someone help me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#contact {
  top: 500px;
  background: #143e8c;
}

#mySidenav a.prev span.arrow {
  background: url(images/arrow_left.png) center center no-repeat;
  /*2.*/
}

#mySidenav a span.arrow {
  display: block;
}

#container span.arrow {
  display: block;
  /*1.*/
}

.myArrow {
  background: url(images/TMlogo.png);
}

div#background-image-position {
  background: white url(https://www.tm.com.my/style%20library/tmap/images/tm-logo-200%20x%20137.png) center center;
  /*3.*/
}

.winners {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background: #FFF url(https://www.tm.com.my/style%20library/tmap/images/tm-logo-200%20x%20137.png) right center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Drinks Menu</li>
    <li>Beer</li>
    <li>Spirits</li>
    <li>Cola</li>
    <li>Lemonade</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="arrow"><!--1. arrow_left.png is suppossed to appear here --></span>
</div>

<div class="myArrow">
  <!---->
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" class="prev" id="contact">
            Project Status
            <span class="arrow"><!--2. arrow_left.png is suppossed to appear here --></span>
          </a>
</div>
<div id='background-image-position'>
  <!--3. tm-logo-200%20x%20137.png is suppossed to appear here -->
</div>
```

Comment: `div#background-image-position { height:200px; .....`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=div+background+not+showing+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.